# Is this possible in c++11? A class with same name but one with template. Ex: Result and Result<T>

Tags: c++, templates

Is this possible in c++11? Two class with same name but one with  template.
Ex:

A class with name `Result` and another with name `Result<T>` to use like

```
return Result("Message");
```

or

```
Result<Date>("Message", date);
```

For example, I tried this without success:

```
 template<>
 class response
 {
     public:
         bool sucess;
         std::string message;
         int code;  
 };

 template<typename T>
 class response<T>
 {
     public:
         T data;
};
```

Comment: you can have a class template called `Result` with a default template argument, but you cannot have two classes with same name. Why do you want that? The question is not quite clear

Comment: In C++17 you could probably write a template deduction guide that would mean that `Result("Message")` creates a `Result<void>` that you'd specialized to have no additional payload. I don't know if there's a way to create the same effect in C++11.

Comment: The compiler will store them as different functions in its function table.  One will be `Result` and if using `int`, the other one would be `Result<int>`.  Two different names, two different functions.

Comment: _Is this possible?_ [No it isn't](https://wandbox.org/permlink/b66aKaSVrr5zMrKH).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple C++11 options:

Provide a default template argument of `void` and specialize on that.

```
template<class T = void>
class response
{
public:
    bool success;
    std::string message;
    int code;
    T data;
};

template<>
class response<void>
{
public:
    bool success;
    std::string message;
    int code;
};
```

Then `response<>` will mean `response<void>` and will not have a `data` member. However, you'd still have to write `response<>("Message")` instead of `response("Message")`

(In your actual code you'd probably want to give `response` constructors so that they could be directly initialized like this.)

---

One option you can use to augment this is with factory functions, because a function overload set can contain both non-templated functions and function templates. So, for instance, you can have a `make_response` function:

```cpp
// Assuming the appropriate response constructors exist
response<> make_response(std::string t_message)
{
    return response<>{t_message};
}

template<class T>
response<T> make_response(std::string t_message, T t_data)
{
    return response<T>{t_message, t_data};
}
```

Then `make_response("Message")` will make a `response<>` aka a `response<void>` that has no `data` member, and `make_response("Message", date)` will make a `response<Date>` that has one.

Comment: Wow Thanks, I was thinking this was not possible.